# Flash imported images have incorrect file sizes

Tags: image, flash, import, compression, filesize

I've just exported a JPG image from Photoshop using the "Save for Web" feature. I got the image down to 58kb.

When I import it into Flash and go into it's Properties to change the compression, the original filesize is stated as 1884.5kb, so I have to then apply compression of around 40% to bring it back down to around 60kb which of course means I loose the quality I had it saved at in Photoshop.

Does anyone know any way around this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the **Compression** to "Photo (JPEG)" and **Quality** to "Use imported JPEG data", that should do what you need. I believe the "original" file size is actually describing the raw bitmap data at 32 bits per pixel.

Comment: I don't see that option unfortunately. Only use publish settings or custom.

Comment: That's odd, those are the options for when you've just copied and pasted an image in, rather than actually importing it. Try selecting the file again through the "Import..." button in the image properties, then close and reopen the properties panel?